# How to find the acceptance rate for a certain conferrence in a certain field?

Tags: conference

I am trying to find the acceptance rate for the 10th WSEAS International Conference on computers. After doing some search on Google and on their website http://www.wseas.org/ I was not able to get a number. It says on their website that their acceptance rate is aprx 20%, but this could be for the most recent conference, and it could be for something other than computers?

I tried to find the proceedings online, but I was not 100% sure if I am looking at the right proceedings.

http://www.worldses.org/online/2011.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know is to **ask them**, i.e., find the contact of one of the editors, and politely ask him/her what was the acceptance rate for that particular year.

There are multiple lists available on the internet:

- http://haofengjia.weebly.com/computer-science.html
- http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~sikora/ratio/confs.php
- http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/conf/stats/
- http://kodu.ut.ee/~dumas/LiquidPub/ConfStats/
- https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~andre/conferences.php
- http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~taoxie/seconferences.htm

as well as the links they provide.

But they are as reliable as your trust in their authors: there is no guarantee whatsoever, in most of the cases, that their sources is trustworthy, and they are very scattered most of the time.

Related questions:

- [Conference ranking in computer science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/85712/19627)
- [Is there any world-wide ranking of conferences/journals?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/is-there-any-world-wide-ranking-of-conferences-journals)